# Compilation error when executing through pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I have a maven project and when I try to execute through pom.xml file, getting the compilation error as follows

C:testscripts/TC_Maintenance.java:[137,48] "strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)"

I have configured jdk 1.8 in maven, could you please resolve this issue.
We have parent pom as well that is called in the pom.xml file

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your pom.xml to your question.

Comment: Also check `java -version` to see that you are truly using jdk 1.8

Comment: Are you trying to trigger maven build using eclipse maven plugin or via command line ?

Answer (score 1):

Please validate compiler option in pom.xml file also validate your maven is using correct java version using `mvn -version`.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  [...]
</project>
```

more details about in [set-compiler-source-and-target](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: yup did, not working
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <!-- <version>3.6.1</version> <configuration> <source>${java.version}</source> 
      <target>${java.version}</target> </configuration> -->
     <version>3.7.0</version>
     <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have added this plugin to your pom.xml. This will ensure that the build task uses version 1.7. We often miss this.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including it as a plug-in, I added the section under properties above Dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

I should add that this is what I believe has already been offered, but I think you added the code in the wrong area of your pom.xml, at least based upon your commented reply (it's hard to read as a comment - no formatting)

Answer (score 0):

By default Maven project takes jre file try to change it to JDK JRE and check whether you are able to resolve this issue.